# How to set buildConfigField for module from outside for android?

Tags: android, android-buildconfig

I am developing in Android, and I have a submodule in my project.

I have set `buildConfigField` like the following in `build.gradle` of Module

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField "String", "TestId", '"48"'
    }
    dev {
        buildConfigField "String", "TestId", '"88"'
    }
}
```

And I use `TestId` in module.

But I want to change the `TestId` from outside, like `build.gradle` of `app`.

How to set the `buildConfigField` of module from `build.gradle` of `app` for Android ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little confusing for me. I don't really get your point. But I want to point out. The buildConfigField will generate corresponding field in BuildConfig. And these fields are decorated by final keyword. So they can't be changed.